# Double Pointers in C and their scope

Tags: c, pointers

I have this code:

```
void alloc2(int** p) {
   *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
   **p = 10;
}

void alloc1(int* p) {
   p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
   *p = 10;
}

int main(){
   int *p;
   alloc1(p);
   //printf("%d ",*p);//value is undefined
   alloc2(&p);
   printf("%d ",*p);//will print 10
   free(p);
   return 0;
}
```

So, I understand that alloc1 just makes a local copy so it's not effecting outside the function the pointer which is given as a parameter.

But what is happening with alloc2?

**tl;dr;**

And why this `alloc1(&p);` won't work?

**Update**

I think i answered my question. The crucial thing is that `&` makes you a pointer and then `a` was built to a double pointer bei dereferencing once. Then the double pointer points to the address given be `malloc`. Finally the address was filled with `10`.

And `alloc1(&p);` would work, but you couldn't derefence the double pointer since it takes a single pointer.

Thanks to all of you

Comment: "Double pointers" *are* normal pointers. They're just pointers that point to other pointers. Just like a "single pointer" is a pointer to points to something that's not a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be clearer if you gave the variables in different functions different names.   Since you have multiple variables and arguments named `p`, and they are distinct from each other, it is easy to confuse yourself.

```
void alloc2(int** pa2)
{
     *pa2 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
     **pa2 = 10;
}

void alloc1(int* pa1) 
{
    pa1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *pa1 = 10;
}

int main()
{
    int *p = 0;
    alloc1(p);
    //printf("%d ",*p);//value is undefined
    alloc2(&p);
    printf("%d ",*p);//will print 10
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Apart from renaming the arguments of functions, I've also initialised `p` in `main()` to zero (the NULL pointer).   You had it uninitialised, which means that even accessing its value (to pass it to `alloc1()`) gives undefined behaviour.

With `p` being NULL, `alloc1()` also receives the NULL pointer as the value of `pa1`.  This is a local copy of the value of `p` from `main()`.   The `malloc()` call then changes the value of `pa1`   (and has no effect on `p` in `main()`, since it is a different variable).   The statement `*pa1 = 10` sets the malloced `int` to be `10`.     Since `pa1` is local to `alloc1()` it ceases to exist when `alloc1()` returns.   The memory returned by `malloc()` is not `free()`d though (`pa1` ceases to exist, but what it points to doesn't) so the result is a memory leak.   When control passes back to `main()`, the value of `p` is still zero (NULL).

The call of `alloc2()` is different, since `main()` passes the address of `p`.   That is the value of `pa2` in `alloc2()`.   The `*pa2 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int))` statement does change the value of `p` in `main()` - to be the value returned by `malloc()`.   The statement `**pa2 = 10` then changes that dynamically allocated `int` to be `10`.

Note also that the `(int *)` on the result of `malloc()` is unnecessary in C.   If you need it, it means one of

1. You have not done `#include <stdlib.h>`.   The type conversion forces the code to compile, but any usage of the `int` - strictly speaking - gives undefined behaviour.   If this is the case, remove the `int *` and add `#include <stdlib.h>`.
2. You are compiling your C code using a C++ compiler.

Comment: thanks peter, so I understand the scope thing, pass by value, pass by reference. I dont understand `*pa2 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int))` why is this not: `pa2 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int))` (without `*`). Because with a `*` you are actually dereferencing the address where it points to. And as you can see `p` points to NULL...

Comment: @int80 `p` has the value `0`, but what is passed to `alloc2()` is `&p`, which is a pointer to `p`. So the parameter `pa2` is a pointer to `p`, not a NULL pointer. Therefore, when `pa2` is dereferenced with `*`, you are assigning a value to `p`.

Comment: so, with the first dereferncing you actually store the address given by malloc into `pa2` instead store a commen value? Hence you can store a value by dereferencing double? I may understand now :)

Answer (score 2):

It didn't become a double pointer, in `alloc2()` you are passing a pointer containing the address of `main()`'s `p`. When you dereference it you are actually modifying the address stored in `main()`'s `p`. And that's why it's working.

Since there is no pass by reference in [c](/questions/tagged/c), the only way you can modify a parameter inside a function is by passing a pointer with it's address, for example if you have to pass an integer to a function and the function needs to modify it then you make a pointer using the address of `&` operator and pass that pointer to the function, example

```
void
modify(int *pointer)
{
    *pointer += 1;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int value;
    value = 0;

    modify(&value);
    printf("%d\n", value);

    modify(&value);
    printf("%d\n", value);
}
```

would output

```
1
2
```

A double pointer is a pointer to a pointer, so you are making a pointer from `p` in `main()` which stores the address of `p` in `main()`, the pointer itself is stored somewhere, so you are passing the address where the pointer is stored and hence you can modify it's contents from within `alloc2()`.

Note: It's bad style to cast the return valud of `malloc()`, [read more about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1983495).

Comment: so what I don't understand are those lines: `*p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));` and `**p = 10;` ... this must be dereferencing?